# How can I set WM_CLASS for Emacs 27?

Tags: frames, emacsclient

I use scratchpads in XMonad (my WM) extensively for quickly capturing (notes, TODOs etc) from anyhwere. I have an instance of Emacs running permanently in a workspace, and launch `emacsclient` as my scratchpad.

XMonad relies on WM_CLASS property of the frame(?) to identify if it should start new emacsclient instance, or if it should reuse it started previously. Before Emacs 27, this is how I used to start emacsclient from XMonad:

```
emacsclient -c --frame-parameters='(quote (name . "scratchmacs"))'
```

Before Emacs 27, doing a `xprops | grep WM_CLASS` would return "scrathmacs", but Emacs 27 keep giving "Emacs" instead. As a result, everytime I call my scratch-pad, a new window for emacsclient opens up :-(

I have done a bunch of googling and read through the documentation (albeit quite non-methodically), but got nowhere.

Evaluating `(assoc 'name (frame-parameters))` in new emacsclient frame gives correct answer, i.e
`scratchmacs` (but xprop for this frame still says `emacs`).

How can I set WM_CLASS of my choice for new emacsclient frames?

Comment: This bug report may be of interest: https://debbugs.gnu.org/41719

Comment: Yeah, this bug is pretty much it. Doesn't look like there is much I can do without headache. I am holding resorting to launch `st -n scratchmacs` and then launching `emacsclient` in it for now.

Answer (score 1):

I've pinged the [bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/41719) as it's still happening in Emacs 28, but in the meantime, I use the following:

```
# emacs.sh:
# call as ./emacs.sh [<file1>] [...]

flock "/run/lock/emacs-wmclassfix-$USER" bash -s "$@" <<'EOF' 
{
        emacsclient --no-wait --create-frame "$@" ||
        exec emacs --name emacs-title -f server-start "$@"
} &
EOF
```

If the server is started by calling `emacs` directly instead of letting `emacsclient` create one, then all goes to plan. This fully fixes the problem for me, without loss of functionality.